# Function in R for assigning a value to data based on if that data fits a range criteria

Tags: r, function, range

I have a data set which contains training data for 24 athletes, where heart rate is recorded every second.

```
date start.time secs    athlete heart_rate
1 2020-01-06  05:30:04     0 John Smith     92.000
2 2020-01-06  05:30:04     1 John Smith     93.500
3 2020-01-06  05:30:04     2 John Smith     95.000
4 2020-01-06  05:30:04     3 John Smith     95.125
5 2020-01-06  05:30:04     4 John Smith     95.250
6 2020-01-06  05:30:04     5 John Smith     95.375
```

There are about 1200 sessions in this `data.frame` totalling 6 million rows of data. I also have a `tibble` containing individualised heart rate zones for each athlete. There are 5 heart rate zones, T1 - T5, each with a minimum value and maximum value.

```
  athlete    T1.HRmin T1.HRmax T2.HRmin T2.HRmax T3.HRmin T3.HRmax T4.HRmin T4.HRmax T5.HRmin T5.HRmax
  <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 John Smith      108      136      137      149      150      161      162      166      167      220
2 Joe Bloggs      139      159      160      175      176      189      190      194      195      220
3 Billy Bob       134      160      161      178      179      194      195      200      201      220
4 Jane Doe        124      146      147      163      164      172      173      177      178      200
5 Sam Smith       124      154      155      164      165      180      181      186      187      201
6 Harry Hat       116      148      149      165      166      177      178      182      183      220
```

I would like to create a new column in the main `data.frame` called `HR.zone` which identifies which heart rate zone the athlete is in by looking up the heart rate value in the individualised heart rate zones specified. The assigned values would be `T0` - for values less than `T1.HRmin`, `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4` and `T5` for the rspecitve values.

I would also like to sum the time spent in each of these HR zones. i.e how long does each athlete spend in the heart rate zone T2.

I have no idea where to begin starting with this, or if it's possible with the formatting I have. 
Appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` approach with a rolling join that I suspect may be faster than the `dplyr` approach.

First, change the data to `data.table` and add an extra heart_rate column so we can keep up with it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[,original_heart_rate := heart_rate]
```

Now set the zones to `data.table`, add some T0 zones, so that we can join on to them later and `melt` to long form. We can use `gsub` to change the zones into a more readable form.

```
setDT(zones)
zones[,T0.min := 1]
zones[,T0.max := T1.HRmin - 1]
zones <- melt(zones,id.vars = "athlete")
zones[,zone := gsub("^([[:alnum:]]+).*","\\1",variable)]
zones[,heart_rate := value]
```

Now perform the magic, the rolling join. We join the zones table onto the data table on both `athlete` and `heart_rate`. When `roll = "nearest"`, the last element of `on =` can be a rolling join to the nearest value.

```
Result <- zones[data,on = c("athlete","heart_rate"),roll = "nearest"]
Result
#      athlete variable value zone heart_rate       date start.time secs original_heart_rate
#1: John Smith   T0.max   107   T0     92.000 2020-01-06   05:30:04    0              92.000
#2: John Smith   T0.max   107   T0     93.500 2020-01-06   05:30:04    1              93.500
#3: John Smith   T0.max   107   T0     95.000 2020-01-06   05:30:04    2              95.000
#4: John Smith   T0.max   107   T0     95.125 2020-01-06   05:30:04    3              95.125
#5: John Smith T5.HRmin   167   T5    170.250 2020-01-07   05:30:04    4             170.250
#6: John Smith T1.HRmax   136   T1    130.375 2020-01-07   05:30:04    5             130.375
```

We see that the rolling join match the heart rate with the appropriate zone based on the nearest value.

Assuming that each row is exactly one second, we can see how many seconds each athlete spends in each zone with a single line.

```
Result[,.N,by= .(athlete,zone)]
#      athlete zone N
#1: John Smith   T0 4
#2: John Smith   T5 1
#3: John Smith   T1 1
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2020-01-06", 
"2020-01-07"), class = "factor"), start.time = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "05:30:04", class = "factor"), 
    secs = 0:5, athlete = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "John Smith", class = "factor"), 
    heart_rate = c(92, 93.5, 95, 95.125, 170.25, 130.375)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

zones <- structure(list(athlete = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("Billy Bob", 
"Harry Hat", "Jane Doe", "Joe Bloggs", "John Smith", "Sam Smith"
), class = "factor"), T1.HRmin = c(108L, 139L, 134L, 124L, 124L, 
116L), T1.HRmax = c(136L, 159L, 160L, 146L, 154L, 148L), T2.HRmin = c(137L, 
160L, 161L, 147L, 155L, 149L), T2.HRmax = c(149L, 175L, 178L, 
163L, 164L, 165L), T3.HRmin = c(150L, 176L, 179L, 164L, 165L, 
166L), T3.HRmax = c(161L, 189L, 194L, 172L, 180L, 177L), T4.HRmin = c(162L, 
190L, 195L, 173L, 181L, 178L), T4.HRmax = c(166L, 194L, 200L, 
177L, 186L, 182L), T5.HRmin = c(167L, 195L, 201L, 178L, 187L, 
183L), T5.HRmax = c(220L, 220L, 220L, 200L, 201L, 220L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It works fine up until the last line ```Result <- zones[data,on = c("athlete","heart_rate"),roll = "nearest"]```. The ```data.table``` ```Result```. contains ```NA``` values for the columns ```variable```, ```value```, and ```zone```

Comment: Now this error ```Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 6310147 rows; more than 6308953 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice```

Comment: Is it possible that the same athlete appears more than once in the heart rate zones table? What happens if you do `by=.EACHI`?

Comment: The fist issue was that there was a blank space at the end of the athlete's name in ```data```, so i cleaned that up. The code seems to work is i run the last line with ```allow.cartesian = TRUE```. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first dataframe is called `df` and the second one `range`, we can get `range` in long format separating min and max columns of heart rate, join it with `df` based on `athlete` name. We can use `findInterval` to know which `T` value `heart_rate` lies and select only unique rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(range %>% 
            tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('T'), 
                                names_to = c('col', '.value'), 
                                names_sep = '\\.'), by = 'athlete') %>%
   group_by(athlete) %>%
   mutate(val = paste0('T', findInterval(heart_rate, sort(HRmin)))) %>%
   distinct(date, start.time, secs, athlete, heart_rate, val)
```

Comment: I keep getting the error ```Error: 'pivot_longer' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'```. I have tried re-installing the package but then i get the following error. ```Error in df %>% left_join(range %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("T"),  : 
  could not find function "%>%"```

Comment: @wattss Please load `library(dplyr)` and `pivot_longer` is from new version of `tidyr`.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I'm not sure it's working quite right. I get `val`s that are outside the range of T1 - T5.